# Boolean flags encoded as integer implemented with EnumSet

Tags: java, enum

I'm a beginner in Java so I would appreciate a review of following simple class - in fact it's my first real usage of enums.

The background: I'm parsing MySQL internal client-server protocol. One of the fields in server greeting and client authorization packet is "Client capabilities" which is 32 bit integer encoding 18 boolean flags ( if anyone is interested: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol#Handshake_Initialization_Packet)

I've read that the most 'java way' to implement such thing will be using EnumSet class.

I'll welcome any suggestions and other solutions - my needs are:

1. I must be able to parse flags from 4 bytes big endian buffer
2. To encode flags back to 4 bytes big endian buffer
3. To check if some arbitrary flag is set

here's the code:

```
public class ClientCapabilities
{
    public enum Flag {
        CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD (1<<0),
        CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS (1<<1),
        CLIENT_LONG_FLAG (1<<2),
        CLIENT_CONNECT_WITH_DB (1<<3),
        CLIENT_NO_SCHEMA (1<<4),
        CLIENT_COMPRESS (1<<5),
        CLIENT_ODBC (1<<6),
        CLIENT_LOCAL_FILES (1<<7),
        CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE (1<<8),
        CLIENT_PROTOCOL_41 (1<<9),
        CLIENT_INTERACTIVE (1<<10),
        CLIENT_SSL (1<<11),
        CLIENT_IGNORE_SIGPIPE (1<<12),
        CLIENT_TRANSACTIONS (1<<13),
        CLIENT_RESERVED (1<<14),
        CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION (1<<15),
        CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS (1<<16),
        CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS (1<<17);

        public final int weight;

        Flag(Integer weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    private final int originalInt;
    private final EnumSet<Flag> flags = EnumSet.noneOf(Flag.class);

    public ClientCapabilities(int capabilities)
    {
        originalInt = capabilities;
        for (Flag f : Flag.values()) {
            if ((capabilities & f.weight) > 0) {
                flags.add(f);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getAsInt()
    {
        return originalInt;
    }

    public EnumSet<Flag> getFlags() 
    {
        return flags;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return flags.toString();
    }

    //only tests ahead - TestNG, not JUnit!
    @Test
    public static void testDecodingClientCapabilities()
    {
        byte[] exampleBuffer = new byte[] { (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00 };
        EnumSet<Flag> expectedEnumSet = EnumSet.of(
                Flag.CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD, 
                Flag.CLIENT_LONG_FLAG,
                Flag.CLIENT_LOCAL_FILES,
                Flag.CLIENT_PROTOCOL_41,
                Flag.CLIENT_INTERACTIVE,
                Flag.CLIENT_TRANSACTIONS,
                Flag.CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION,
                Flag.CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS,
                Flag.CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS
        );


        ClientCapabilities capabilities = new ClientCapabilities(
                PacketByteBuffer.readIntFromFourBytes(exampleBuffer,0));

        Assert.assertEquals(capabilities.getFlags(), expectedEnumSet);
    }

    @Test
    public static void testEncodingClientCapabilities()
    {
        byte[] exampleBuffer = new byte[] { (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00 };
        byte[] targetBuffer = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        ClientCapabilities capabilities = new ClientCapabilities(
                PacketByteBuffer.readIntFromFourBytes(exampleBuffer,0));

        PacketByteBuffer.writeIntToFourBytes(targetBuffer, 1, capabilities.originalInt);

        Assert.assertEquals(targetBuffer[1], (byte) 0x85);
        Assert.assertEquals(targetBuffer[2], (byte) 0xa6);
        Assert.assertEquals(targetBuffer[3], (byte) 0x03);
        Assert.assertEquals(targetBuffer[4], (byte) 0x00);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks fine. Some notes about the tests:

Test methods should be in another class (`ClientCapabilitiesTest`) and in a separate source tree. For example, Maven projects usually store sources under `src/main/java` and test sources under `src/test/java`. ([Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)).

---

The [first parameter of `assertEquals` is the expected value](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28long,%20long%29) and the second is the actual one, so you should change

```
assertEquals(targetBuffer[1], (byte) 0x85);
```

to

```
assertEquals((byte) 0x85, targetBuffer[1]);
```

JUnit error messages assumes this order.

---

Create more tests which helps [defect localization](http://xunitpatterns.com/Goals%20of%20Test%20Automation.html#Defect%20Localization). A parameterized test class would be fine:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.EnumSet;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ClientCapabilitiesTest {

    private final byte[] input;
    private final EnumSet<Flag> expected;

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        // TODO: add more cases
        final Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
                { new byte[] { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 },
                        EnumSet.of(Flag.CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD) },
                { new byte[] { (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 }, 
                        EnumSet.of(Flag.CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS) },
                { new byte[] { (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 },
                        EnumSet.of(Flag.CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD, Flag.CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS) },
                { new byte[] { (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00 },
                        EnumSet.of(Flag.CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD, 
                                Flag.CLIENT_LONG_FLAG, 
                                Flag.CLIENT_LOCAL_FILES,
                                Flag.CLIENT_PROTOCOL_41, 
                                Flag.CLIENT_INTERACTIVE, 
                                Flag.CLIENT_TRANSACTIONS,
                                Flag.CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION, 
                                Flag.CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS, 
                                Flag.CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS) } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    public ClientCapabilitiesTest(final byte[] input, final EnumSet<Flag> expected) {
        this.input = input;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void testDecodingClientCapabilities() {
        final ClientCapabilities capabilities = new ClientCapabilities(
            PacketByteBuffer.readIntFromFourBytes(input, 0));

        Assert.assertEquals(expected, capabilities.getFlags());
    }
}
```

I'd add one case for every flag and some cases with multiple enabled flags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention that tests are in TestNG (and it seems they have opposite expected-actual parameter order).

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me. The only thing I have to notice is that `if ((capabilities & f.weight) > 0)` should instead be `if ((capabilities & f.weight) != 0)`. The reason for this is that if you were using bit #31 (the 32nd bit) then the expression `capabilities & f.weight` would yield a negative number, so it would not pass the test for `> 0`.