# ANDing ints in Java

Tags: java, bitwise

Is there any better way than doing:

```
if ((newState & InputState.DEFAULT) == InputState.DEFAULT)
```

?
My InputState.class defines static int variables to the power of 2 that are being ORed with an int to make it possible to determine more than one input state. However, checking the existence of a set bit like this looks just odd to me (and means writing alot of code that is obvious to come anyway) I was wondering whether there is a better solution to that.

Comment: Problem is only that we don't have much to review. Maybe take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/boolean-flags-encoded-as-integer-implemented-with-enumset

Comment: or just use `if ((newState & InputState.DEFAULT) != 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write an utility method.

```
public static bool CheckMask(int value, int mask){
    return (value & mask) == mask;
}
```

Use it:

```
if(CheckMask(newState, InputState.DEFAULT))
```